# ASP.NET core call async init on singleton service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a service that asynchronously reads some content from a file in a method called `InitAsync`

```
public class MyService : IService {
    private readonly IDependency injectedDependency;

    public MyService(IDependency injectedDependency) {
        this.injectedDependency = injectedDependency;
    }

    public async Task InitAsync() {
        // async loading from file.
    }
}
```

Now this service is injected into my controller.

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private readonly IService service;

    public MyController(IService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Now I want a singleton instance of MyService. And I want to call InitAsync in startup.

```
public class Startup {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        ......
        services.AddSingleton<IService, MyService>();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        // perform async init.
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService>().InitAsync();
    }
}
```

What is happening is at the time of startup, an instance of MyService is created and `InitAsync()` is called on it. Then when I called the controller class, another instance of MyService  is created which is then reused for consequent calls.

What I need is to initialize only 1 instance, called InitAsync() on it in startup and have it be reused by controllers as well.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042989/what-are-the-costs-and-possible-side-effects-of-calling-buildserviceprovider-i/56058498#56058498

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924027/avoiding-all-di-antipatterns-for-types-requiring-asynchronous-initialization

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> What is happening is at the time of startup, an instance of MyService is created and InitAsync() is called on it. Then when I called the controller class, another instance of MyService is created which is then reused for consequent calls.

When you call `BuildServiceProvider()`, you create a separate instance of `IServiceProvider`, which creates its own singleton instance of `IService`. The `IServiceProvider` that gets used when resolving the `IService` that's provided for `MyController` is different to the one you created yourself and so the `IService` itself is also different (and uninitialised).

> What I need is to initialize only 1 instance, called InitAsync() on it in startup and have it be reused by controllers as well.

Rather than attempting to resolve and initialise `IService` inside of `Startup.ConfigureServices`, you can do so in `Program.Main`. This allows for two things:

1. Using the *same* instance of `IService` for initialisation and later use.
2. `await`ing the call to `InitAsync`, which is currently fire-and-forget in the approach you've shown.

Here's an example of how `Program.Main` might look:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

    await webHost.Services.GetRequiredService<IService>().InitAsync();

    webHost.Run();
    // await webHost.RunAsync();
}
```

This uses [`async Main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main) to enable use of `await`, builds the `IWebHost` and uses its `IServiceProvider` to resolve and initialise `IService`. The code also shows how you can use `await` with `RunAsync` if you prefer, now that the method is `async`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply way to do that with nuget [HostInitActions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HostInitActions)

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {       
        services.AddSingleton<IService, MyService>();

        services.AddAsyncServiceInitialization()
            .AddInitAction<IService>(async (service) =>
            {
                await service.InitAsync();
            });
    }
```

This nugget ensures that your initialization action will be performed asynchronously before the application starts.

Another advantage of this approach is that this initialization action can be defined from any place where services are installed into the IServiceCollection (For example, in an extension method in another project that installs internal implementations of public interfaces). This means that the ASP.NET Core project does not need to know what service and how it should be initialized, and it will still be done.

Comment: That still initialized as part of hosted service creation/start which is too late for things that require hosted service dependencies to be initialized